# change running user for tomcat - error 500

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

Historically, we had several Linux environments running apps on tomcat 9.0.22 as root user.
For security reason I want to switch to a less privileged user created for that purpose.
I changed the tomcat.service adding :

```
User=etemptation
Group=etemptation
```

And the ownership of the tomcat directory using :

```
chown -R etemptation:etemptation /appli/tomcat
```

It worked for PROD and n°1 INT environnement but oddly, I can't make it works for the second INT environnement.
Visually, I get en loging error page saying "An error occured" and in the tomcat access_log I see 1 error 500 the several 404 error :

```
172.20.45.88 - - [30/Mar/2023:17:07:39 +0200] "GET /webquartz/ HTTP/1.1" 500 398
172.20.45.88 - - [30/Mar/2023:17:07:39 +0200] "GET /js/dream.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1011
172.20.45.88 - - [30/Mar/2023:17:07:39 +0200] "GET /css/auth.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1012
172.20.45.88 - - [30/Mar/2023:17:07:39 +0200] "GET /css/styleeTempora.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1021
172.20.45.88 - - [30/Mar/2023:17:07:39 +0200] "GET /css/auth.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1012
172.20.45.88 - - [30/Mar/2023:17:07:39 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

The catalina log does not show any error, just like the application log (webquartz). I compared the two INT environnement to no avail.

What can be the cause of this behaviour and how to solve it ?

Many thanks.